# Error in reading YAML in ruby, what to do when the header is missing?

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll

I have a markdown file which should have a YAML front matter in it (a Jekyll post file). I read the YAML part of the file with

```
yaml = YAML.load_file(filename)
```

Now when the file contains the YAML part no problem, otherwise exits with an error.

**My question is:** how do you handle this error in ruby such that the program notifies me of the missing header but still continues to execute the rest of the code?

Comment: The header is optional in YAML. What does the YAML data look like and what's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @Jordan I have a Jekyll post Markdown file with a yaml frontmatter (header). Now some of the markdown drafts i'm writing do not (still) have the yaml part.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
begin
  yaml = YAML.load_file(filename)
rescue
  #log or notification code here
end
```

Comment: `next` doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks! need to try it as soon as I get back home